# NuSMV - AND model

Tags: model-checking, nusmv

I'm trying to write the following model in NuSMV

[image]

In other words, z becomes bad only when x AND y are in the state bad too. This is the code I've written

```
MODULE singleton
    VAR state: {good, bad};
    INIT state = good
    TRANS (state = good) -> next(state) = bad
    TRANS (state = bad) -> next(state) = bad

MODULE effect(cond)
    VAR state: {good, bad};
    ASSIGN
    init(state) := good;
    next(state) := case
        (state = bad) : bad;
        (state = good & cond) : bad;
        (!cond) : good;
        TRUE : state;
        esac;

MODULE main 
    VAR x : singleton;
    VAR y : singleton;
    VAR z : effect((x.state = bad) & (y.state = bad));
```

But I got only these reachable states

```
NuSMV > print_reachable_states -v
######################################################################
system diameter: 3
reachable states: 3 (2^1.58496) out of 8 (2^3)
  ------- State    1 ------
  x.state = good
  y.state = good
  z.state = good
  ------- State    2 ------
  x.state = bad
  y.state = bad
  z.state = bad
  ------- State    3 ------
  x.state = bad
  y.state = bad
  z.state = good
  -------------------------
######################################################################
```

How can I modify my code to get also

```
x.state = good
y.state = bad
z.state = good

x.state = bad
y.state = good
z.state = good
```

in the reachable states?

In addition, I'm not sure if I've to add or not that red arrow printed in the model picture: if x and y are in state bad, I want that for sure sooner or later also z becomes bad.

Thank you so much for helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The states

```sh
x.state = good
y.state = bad
z.state = good

x.state = bad
y.state = good
z.state = good
```

are not reachable because each sub-module of `main` performs a transition at the same time of the others and because you *force* a *deterministic* transition for your *state variables*; that is, in your model both `x` and `y` change state from `good` to `bad` at the same time. Moreover, in contrast with your nice picture, your `smv` code does not allow for any self-loop except for the one on the final state.

---

To fix your model, you need only to state that --in case `x` (resp. `y`) is `good`-- you want `next(x)` (resp. `next(y)`) to be either `good` or `bad`, but not force either decision. **e.g.**

```sh
MODULE singleton
VAR
  state: { good, bad };

ASSIGN
  init(state) := good;
  next(state) := case
      state = good : { good, bad };
      TRUE         : bad;
    esac;


MODULE effect(cond)
VAR
  state: { good, bad };

ASSIGN
  init(state) := good;
  next(state) := case
      (state = bad | cond) : bad;
      TRUE                 : state;
    esac;


MODULE main
VAR
    x : singleton;
    y : singleton;
    z : effect((x.state = bad) & (y.state = bad));
```

***note:*** i also simplified the rules for module `effect`, though this was unnecessary.

You can test the model as follows:

```sh
nuXmv > reset; read_model -i test.smv ; go; print_reachable_states -v
######################################################################
system diameter: 3
reachable states: 5 (2^2.32193) out of 8 (2^3)
  ------- State    1 ------
  x.state = good
  y.state = bad
  z.state = good
  ------- State    2 ------
  x.state = good
  y.state = good
  z.state = good
  ------- State    3 ------
  x.state = bad
  y.state = good
  z.state = good
  ------- State    4 ------
  x.state = bad
  y.state = bad
  z.state = bad
  ------- State    5 ------
  x.state = bad
  y.state = bad
  z.state = good
  -------------------------
######################################################################
```

---

Regarding your second question, the *code sample* I provided you guarantees the property you want to verify:

```sh
nuXmv > check_ltlspec -p "G ((x.state = bad & y.state = bad) -> F z.state = bad)"
-- specification  G ((x.state = bad & y.state = bad) ->  F z.state = bad)  is true
```

This is obviously the case because the *self-loop* outlined by the *red edge* in your picture *is not present*. If you think about it, that transition would allow for at least one execution in which the *current state* remains equal to

```sh
x.state = bad
y.state = bad
z.state = good
```

indefinitely, and this would be a counter-example to your specification.

---

**EDIT:**

You can also fix the code by simply writing this:

```
MODULE singleton
    VAR state: {good, bad};
    INIT state = good
    TRANS (state = bad) -> next(state) = bad
```

Removing the line `TRANS (state = good) -> next(state) = bad` allows `x` and `y` to change arbitrarily when `state = good`, which means they can non-deterministically remain `good` or become `bad`. This is completely equivalent to the code I provided you, although less clear at a first glance since it hides *non-determinism* under the hoods instead of making it explicit.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I finally understand what was wrong with my code :)